# Allowing Class Library to use App.config from UI Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I recently decoupled my UI layer from my Models and Service layer by splitting them into separate projects. Now I get the following error upon compiling my solution:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'An error occurred creating the configuration section handler 
for IOLegend: Could not load file or assembly 'Laborare.Core' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

In my class library, I use ConfigurationManager to read application configuration settings such as:

```
var IoLegendConfig = (IOLegendConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("IOLegend");
var Rs232Config = (RS232ConnectionConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RS232Connection");
public static string _Metric_Setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["metric_setting"];
```

Here is my configSections in the app.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="TCPConnection"
             type="Laborare.Core.Configuration.TCPConnectionConfig, Laborare.Core"/>

    <section name="RS232Connection"
             type="Laborare.Core.Configuration.RS232ConnectionConfig, Laborare.Core"/>

    <section name="IOLegend"
             type="Laborare.Core.Configuration.IOLegendConfig, Laborare.Core" />
    
  </configSections>
```

The app.config is located in my UI project. What is the problem here? Am I not correctly directing the ConfigurationManager in my class library? I seem to be using the correct namespaces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a picture of my current solution structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZzTO.png)

Comment: Did you try in Solution Explorer, copying your App.config from Akoustis90142UI down to your Labradore.Core project?  Your class library has no knowledge of your UI project or the UI project's files.

Comment: Thanks @Tam. It was a hard find but it was actually because when I split my solution into two projects, VS didn't completely update the namespaces in obscure locations.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it resolved.